# Format String After Certain Number of Characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having issues with text that users enter into a `Textbox` since not all users enter text in the correct manner. The users should be entering their text in the following format

```
xx xxxxxx xxxxxx x
```

Is there a way that I can take any text they enter (normally in the format of `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`) and have it automatically add spaces?

I've looked into `Regex`, `InsertAt`, `Replace`, and `LastIndex`, but I'm not sure how to make it work. It's worth mentioning that the text is a string of numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to implement what is mentioned in the links below, but I guess I just don't understand `Regex` enough to make it work.

[Use Regex in C# to insert spaces between ConcatenatedFileNamesLikeThis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695624/use-regex-in-c-sharp-to-insert-spaces-between-concatenatedfilenameslikethis?rq=1)

[How to insert spaces between characters using Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614255/how-to-insert-spaces-between-characters-using-regex)

[Regex to insert space C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029252/regex-to-insert-space-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm not sure regex is the best solution for your problem, but if you still want to use it I would recommend playing around with a regex tool such as regex101.com. For the record, you can probably accomplish what you're trying to do by matching `^(\d{2})(\d{6})(\d{6})(\d)$` and replacing with `\1 \2 \3 \4`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using WinForms, the **MaskedEdit** control will force your users to provide input in the precise format that you have specified. Just supply your input mask at design-time using the **Mask** property and leave the rest to the control.

For your specific format, your mask should be: `## ###### ###### #`. Note that a `#` in the mask is placeholder for one **required** digit. For full details of the mask placeholders, see [Using the MaskedEdit Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733654(v=vs.60).aspx) topic in MSDN.